# how to get UDP connection in infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, udp

I am trying to write a program to implement the distance vector algorithm.
So I need the node to act as both the server and the client.

Basically I am using UDP protocol to send and receive messages. I am trying to listen for message from neighbouring nodes while sending the node's distance vector out every 5 seconds.

My main problem is that I want the stop listening for message so that I can broadcast my distance vector. I tried using `setSoTimeout` but then I get all sorts of exception that I dont know how to handle. and I am not too sure how to "reopen" the socket again to either wait for the message again or move on to broadcasting the message....

Can anybody please point me to the right direction?

My code is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class dv_routing {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //initialise variables to default value
    int NodeID = 0;
    int NodePort = 6000;
    String configFile = "A.txt";
    int numNbr = 0;                                     // zero neighbour
    double[] CostList = new double[10];                 //Self cost list
    Arrays.fill(CostList, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    int[] ViaList = new int[10];                        //Self cost list
    Arrays.fill(ViaList, 9999);
    double[] Cost = new double[10];                     //Inf cost array for Nbr initialization
    Arrays.fill(Cost, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);        
    Neighbour Nbr = new Neighbour();                    //create Nbr
    boolean ischanged = false;


    //read user input
    if (args.length >= 3) {
        System.out.println("i'm here!");
        String tmp = args[0];
        char tmpchar = tmp.charAt(0);
        NodeID = ((int)tmpchar - 65);
        NodePort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        configFile = args[2];
        CostList[NodeID] = 0;
        System.out.println(NodeID);
        System.out.println(NodePort);
        System.out.println(configFile);
        //poison reverse
        if (args.length <= 4) {
            // TODO: poison reverse
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input Format! Please try again!");
    }


       //reading config file for neighbour data
    try{

          // Open the file that is the first 
          // command line parameter
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
          // Get the object of DataInputStream
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String strLine;
          //capture the number neighbours
          if ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
              numNbr = Integer.parseInt(strLine);
              System.out.println (numNbr);
          }
          int elementcnt = 0;
          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              //separate data 
              String[] temp = strLine.split(" ");

              //get neighbour Node ID
              char tmpchar = temp[0].trim().charAt(0);
              int ID = (int)(tmpchar - 65);
              //NbrIDList.add(new NbrID((int)tmpchar - 65));
              //get neighbour cost
              CostList[ID] = Double.parseDouble(temp[1].trim());
              ViaList[ID] = ID;
              //get neighbour port number
              int Port = Integer.parseInt(temp[2].trim());

              //create entry for neighbour
              Nbr.addData(ID, Port);
              Nbr.addCost(Cost);

              //debugging
              //System.out.println((char)(Nbr.getID(elementcnt)+65));
              //System.out.println(Nbr.getPort(elementcnt));
              //System.out.println(Nbr.getCost(elementcnt)[0]);

              elementcnt++;
          }
          //Close the input stream
          in.close();
            }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }



    //set timers
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = now + 50 * 1000;
    long broadcast = now + 1 * 1000;
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(current < end) {
        System.out.println("in first layer");

        //open UDP socket for listening..
        DatagramSocket nodeSocket = new DatagramSocket(NodePort);
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

        //braodcast...
        String OutMsg = CostList[0]+"\t"+CostList[1]+"\t"+CostList[2]+"\t"+CostList[3]+"\t"+CostList[4]+"\t"+CostList[5]+"\t"+CostList[6]+"\t"+CostList[7]+"\t"+CostList[8]+"\t"+CostList[9];
        sendData = OutMsg.getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < numNbr; i++){
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, Nbr.getPort(i));
            nodeSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }

        nodeSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);

        while(current < broadcast){
            if (nodeSocket.isClosed()){
                nodeSocket = new DatagramSocket(NodePort);
            }
            System.out.println("in receiving layer");
            current = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ischanged = false;
            //get MSG
            // Msg format.. "cost1"\t"cost2"\t"cost3"...
            try{DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            nodeSocket.receive(receivePacket);

            System.out.println("we got here");
            String Msg = new String( receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + Msg);
            int NbrPort = receivePacket.getPort();
            System.out.println("From: " + NbrPort);

            //process the MSG
            String[] tmpstr = Msg.split("\t");
            for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
                Cost[i] = Double.parseDouble(tmpstr[i]);
            }
            int Idx = Nbr.indexOfPort(NbrPort);
            System.out.println("From: " + NbrPort);
            Nbr.updateCost(Idx, Cost);

            //compare cost and update list
            for (int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
                double NbrNodeCost = (Nbr.getCost(Idx)[i] + CostList[Nbr.getID(Idx)]);
                if (!(Double.isInfinite(NbrNodeCost)) && CostList[i] > NbrNodeCost) {
                    CostList[i] = NbrNodeCost;
                    ViaList[i] = Nbr.getID(Idx);
                    ischanged = true;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Is the list changed? " + ischanged);
            System.out.println(CostList[0]+" "+CostList[1]+" "+CostList[2]+" "+CostList[3]+" "+CostList[4]+" "+CostList[5]+" "+CostList[6]+" "+CostList[7]+" "+CostList[8]+" "+CostList[9]);
            System.out.println(ViaList[0]+" "+ViaList[1]+" "+ViaList[2]+" "+ViaList[3]+" "+ViaList[4]+" "+ViaList[5]+" "+ViaList[6]+" "+ViaList[7]+" "+ViaList[8]+" "+ViaList[9]);
            }catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                //System.err.println("Caught SocketException: " + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Timeout reached!!! " + e);
                nodeSocket.close();
                nodeSocket = new DatagramSocket(NodePort);
                current = System.currentTimeMillis();

            }
            catch (SocketException e1){
                System.out.println("Socket closed " + e1);
            }

        }
        //Broadcast List
        System.out.println("broadcast");

        broadcast = current + 1 * 1000;
        current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (ischanged) {
            end = current + 10 * 1000;
        }
        //braodcast...
        OutMsg = CostList[0]+"\t"+CostList[1]+"\t"+CostList[2]+"\t"+CostList[3]+"\t"+CostList[4]+"\t"+CostList[5]+"\t"+CostList[6]+"\t"+CostList[7]+"\t"+CostList[8]+"\t"+CostList[9];
        sendData = OutMsg.getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < numNbr; i++){
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, Nbr.getPort(i));
            nodeSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }

    }

    //Print List
    //Shortest path to node B: the next hop is C and the cost is 5
    for(int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        if(ViaList[i] != 9999){
            System.out.println("Shortest path to node "+(char)(i+65)+": the next hop is "+(char)(ViaList[i])+" and the cost is "+CostList[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("end");


}


}

class Neighbour {

public Neighbour(){
    NbrIDList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    NbrPortList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    NbrCostList = new ArrayList<double[]>();
}

public void addData(int ID, int Port){
    NbrIDList.add(ID);
    NbrPortList.add(Port);
}

public void addCost(double[] Cost){
    NbrCostList.add(Cost);
}

public int getID(int idx){
    return (Integer) NbrIDList.get(idx);
}

public int getPort(int idx){
    return (Integer) NbrPortList.get(idx);
}

public int indexOfPort(int Port){
    return (Integer) NbrPortList.indexOf(Port);
}

public double[] getCost(int idx){
    return (double[]) NbrCostList.get(idx);
}

public void updateCost(int idx, double[] Cost){
    NbrCostList.set(idx,Cost);
}

private ArrayList<Integer> NbrIDList;
private ArrayList<Integer> NbrPortList;
private ArrayList<double[]> NbrCostList;

}
```

Comment: It appears you want to do two things at once so I suggest you use another thread.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'UDP connection'. Your title at least needs amendment.

Answer (score 2):

Networking is almost 99,8% threading. To solve your problem, you can create one thread to receiving messages and second one for sending message every 5 seconds.

There was a lot of questions about this:

[Java: Multithreading & UDP Socket Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687238/java-multithreading-udp-socket-programming)

[How can I implement a threaded UDP based server in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773121/how-can-i-implement-a-threaded-udp-based-server-in-java)

java2s is also good:

[Server](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/0141__UDP-Server.htm)

[Client](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/0140__UDP-Client.htm)

Comment: Perhaps you could improve your answer with an example?

Comment: i am totally new to multithreading programming but i will try doing reading first.
so assuming i can create 2 threads, one receiving, one broadcasting and i could pass data across..
does it mean that i need to create 2 separate socket on 2 different port for the 2 purposes?

Comment: I am just wondering if there is a way to stop the receiving process without killing the whole program.. and then restarting later on..
if that is possible, then i wouldnt really have to have 2 threads running.. right?